# read and write from files or from cin and cout

Tags: c++

my code work good when the argc is 1 but when I try to read and write from files (when argc is 3)
the program not working well. Gcalc get the ostream (output file or cout) and current line in input file
or cin and decode the string to command on gcalc data.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Gcalc.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Gcalc gcalc;
    string current_line;
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    if (argc != 1 && argc != 3) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc == 3) {
       input = ifstream(argv[1]);
       cin.rdbuf(input.rdbuf());
       output = ofstream(argv[2]);
       cout.rdbuf(output.rdbuf());
   }
   while (cin.good()) {
       if (argc == 1) {
            cout << "Gcalc> ";
       }
       getline(cin, current_line);
       try {
           gcalc.implementCommand(cout, current_line);
       }
       catch (Quit_Program& error) {
             break;
       }
       catch (std::bad_alloc& error) {
             std::cerr << "Error: fatal error - bad allocation" << endl;
             break;
       }
       catch (Exception& error) {
            cout << error.what() << endl;
       } 
   }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: "The program not working well" isn't a good error description. I am sure the program is exactly doing this, what the code says.

Comment: OT: You probably can move `getline(cin, current_line)` into the condition of the while like this: `while (getline(cin, current_line)) {` ...

Comment: My advice is put all the code in the while() loop in a function having 1 parameter which is an istream passed by reference. That way you can pass `cin` or an open file.

Comment: why are you doing this ***argc != 1*** ???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ To exit the program if an incorrect amount of arguments was supplied.

Comment: Ran: Did you abandon this question? Please ask if my answer isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

- Check that opening the files was done successfully.
- Check that the `istream` you read from doesn't have the `failbit` set *after* you've read from it. Since an `istream` in a boolean context checks `badbit` and `failbit` and that `std::getline` returns the same `istream` you gave it, replace your `while (cin.good())` with:

  ```
  while(getline(cin, current_line)) {
      // ... only entered if badbit and failbit are false ...
  }
  ```

That said, it's usually better to create a separate function for reading/writing to generic `istream`/`ostream`s. This way you don't have to mess with the `rdbuf`s of `cin` and `cout`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Gcalc.h"

void do_stuff(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) {
    Gcalc gcalc;
    std::string current_line;

    while(getline(is, current_line)) {
        try {
            gcalc.implementCommand(os, current_line);
        } catch(Quit_Program& error) {
            break;
        } catch(const std::bad_alloc& error) {
            std::cerr << "Error: fatal error - " << error.what() << std::endl;
            break;
        } catch(Exception& error) {
            std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
            // or, if you really want it:
            // os << error.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1) {
        do_stuff(std::cin, std::cout);
    } else if(argc == 3) {
        std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
        std::ofstream output(argv[2]);
        if(input && output) do_stuff(input, output);
    }
}
```

If you want to give the user a prompt when the program is running in interactive mode, you could add a function that prints the prompt and then calls `std::getline`. You can combine this inside the `while` loop, but it looks messy, so I would suggest something like this:

```
std::istream& prompt(std::istream& is, std::string& line) {
    if(&is == &std::cin) std::cout << "Gcalc> ";
    return std::getline(is, line);
}

// ...

    while(prompt(is, current_line)) {
        // ...
    }
```